# MrJob spends a lot of time Copying local files into hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mrjob

The problem I'm encountering is this:
Having already put my `input.txt` (50MBytes) file into HDFS, I'm running

```
python ./test.py hdfs:///user/myself/input.txt -r hadoop --hadoop-bin /usr/bin/hadoop
```

It seems that MrJob spends a lot of time copying files to hdfs (again?)

```
Copying local files into hdfs:///user/myself/tmp/mrjob/test.myself.20150927.104821.148929/files/
```

Is this logical? Shouldn't it use `input.txt` directly from HDFS?

(Using Hadoop version 2.6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the contents of `hdfs:///user/myself/tmp/mrjob/test.myself.20150927.104821.148929/files/` and you will see that `input.txt` isn't the file that's being copied into HDFS.

What's being copied is mrjob's entire python directory, so that it can be unpacked on each of your nodes. (mrjob assumes that mrjob is not installed on each of the nodes in your cluster.)